# it is related to setInterval & setTimeout timers functions when does it start working and how functions will get to know that their job started?

Tags: javascript, timer, event-handling, dom-events

The setInterval and setTimeout timers function when does it start working and how functions will get to know that their job started?

Suppose if I want to run one function once in a day. I need to set constant time for that to start, is there any particular way or method present in Javascript to perform this.

Let's take an example:

example1:

```
    setInterval(check,10800000); 
//3hours = 10800000 ms
```

example 2:

```
setInterval(check,64800000); 
    //18 hours = 64800000 mili s
```

When does `check()` start working and how `check()` will get to know that their term to start there work?

Is that `check()` starts working after loading the page which holds the code?

Comment: So you need to run check() at a certain time of day?

Comment: yes @AntonRusak and it should run only once in a day

Comment: And where do you plan to run this code?

Comment: let's assume in the Medicin database for some medicines there will be an expiry date for each of them. I want to delete those from the database in a daily manner :) so I want to run this function once in a day at a certain point of time.

Comment: I mean, you want to run it in a browser or on a server?

Comment: oops... sorry it is on server side

Comment: So you're going to use nodejs as a server?

Comment: no, it is PHP code.

Comment: The use some PHP task scheduler, why bother with JS?

Comment: Thank you @AntonRusak it is a good view! I'll check it out 

and also I want to know when does check() start working and how check() will get to know that their term to start there work?

is that check() starts working after loading the page which holds the code?

Comment: If the code is on a web page and is loaded in a web browser, setTimeout sets a timer to a number of milliseconds that you have written as a second argument. Whe the timer fires, the callback function is called.

For example, if you write setTimeout(check, 1000) in a script on a page and load that page, check() will be called 1 second later. If you close the page before the timer fires, nothing will happen.